# How to force a library(pybind11) to include <Python.h> from Python3?

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I'm using [pybind11](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) library to create Python bindings for my C++ code.

When I compile my binding code file which includes `<pybind11/pybind11.h>`, it generates the following error:

```
/usr/local/include/pybind11/detail/common.h:112:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file
      not found
#include <Python.h>
```

I could fix this error by changing it to `#include <Python/Python.h>` but the library uses Python 2.7 to generate bindings.

So I tried changing it to `#include "/usr/local/Cellar/python/3.7.6_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/include/python3.7m/Python.h"` and now the library uses Python 3.7 to generate bindings which is what I want.

Although this method works, I wonder if there's any cleaner way to make the library always include headers from Python3 instead of Python2.

Thank you in advance!

P.S: I'm using macOS 10.15.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of ways, but AFAIK, none are consistent across all platforms (which is why something like cmake (see: https://github.com/pybind/cmake_example) is often preferred).

First, there is `python-config`, i.e. add:

```
`python-config --includes`
```

(with back-ticks) to the CLI. My problem with it, is that it is found through `$PATH` (thus need not match the version of `python` that you are running if that installation did not have  a `python-config`) and depending on the distribution, there may be both `python-config` and `python3-config` for `python2` and `python3` respectively.

Second, there is module distutils:

```
`python3 -c 'import distutils.sysconfig as ds; print(ds.get_python_inc())'`
```

which has the advantage of being run from the actual `python` that you choose. In general, distutils isn't fully consistent across platforms either, but `get_python_inc` is a safe bet.